# Why do xy =0 and yx=0 have different graphs?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, graphing-functions

I was graphing on Desmos.
I typed xy = 0 and got the graph of only y=0. Confused I typed yx=0 . I got the graph of only x=0. As far as I know, the equation represents both x=0 and y=0 . 
Is this just a software error or  am I not understanding something crucial?

Comment: WolframAlpha gets it right. Consider sending Desmos a bug report.

Comment: Similar phenomenon with $f(x)g(y)$, $f(x)g(x,y)$, $g(x,y)f(x)$,  $f(y)g(x,y)$, $g(x,y)f(y)$...

Answer (score 3):

Since $xy=yx$, $xy=0\Leftrightarrow yx=0$. Therefore, it must be a software error.

EDIT: For the benefit of future readers, here is a summary of what we uncovered in the comments below: very simple locus definitions solve for only one variable, but $xy= 0x^3+0y^3$ will force the use of a more complex algorithm without this bug.

Comment: But it's Desmos. And there haven't been errors like these even when considering largely complex equations.  I have a intuition of something strange being the reason.

Comment: @user68153 Both axes should be marked as part of the locus for each problem, so if your eyes say otherwise either their code commits a division fallacy (which might not have affected your "complex" equations) or you're not interpreting colours right.

Comment: Interestingly, $\left(x\ ^2-1\right)y\left(y^2-1\right)=0$ shows an H shape, whatever the order of the factors.

Comment: @YvesDaoust As opposed to a square with its sides continuing forever, plus the line $y=0$. I'd love to see an excerpt of their codebase that causes the error.

Comment: Maybe there's something else to explain.... It can't just be software... As Yves Daoust pointed out.. There's a H shape... Where's y=0? Where's y=+-1?

Comment: And (x^2 -1)(y^2-1) =0 and (y^2-1)(x^2-1)=0 are completely different.... Only the one nearer to equals to(=) is being plotted... Why?

Comment: @user68153 All interesting questions, but the only way to address them is to tell Desmos what happens, then see if they can fix them. Even if they do, they'll probably never publicly state what their old code did.

Comment: How do you report them?  Through play store?  I don't know if they have "Report" option in their app.

Comment: Software bugs are not uncommon. Mathematica has some major, major bugs that have existed for a long time that they have no intention to fix. I've submitted a few bug reports myself and they're still there.

Comment: @CameronWilliams: do you have an example ?

Comment: @user68153: There appears to be a feedback form in the help menu (the question mark icon at the top right corner of the website).

Comment: @Rahul Thanks.  I have emailed them about the issue.  Hope they'll fix it soon.

Comment: I have received a follow up email... They say that for very simple equations, they use a normal plotter instead of implicit one... To save time.. But normal plotter tends to solve only one variable.. To get both equations we can type xy= 0x^3+0y^3 to trick the program to use its implicit plotter.     It was afterall a software glitch.. Thank you everyone!